# Which ML algorithm suits best for discrete input data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm

Let suppose I have discrete inputs like below and I have to predict which insurance package(among 12 packages) suits best.

- age
- occupation(one in 30 categories)
- credit rating(0 to 20)
- number of accidents

I have been thinking to use NN, but as I have very diverse set of inputs does really $f(wx + b)$ at a neuron can trace proper prediction? If Yes then which activation function I have to choose?

And I also had thought about SVM but one of my colleague said that SVM's may not do best at multi-class labeling, is this correct?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: Try Random Forest.

Comment: Agree with @Nikolas Rieble. 3 months ago I did a big project on predicting payment delinquencies. 4 methods were tried; logistic regression, gradient boosting (with classification trees), random forests and support vector machines. Gradient boosting and random forests came out as the best performers, within a significance margin from one another. SVM did not perform that well. But, more importantly, they were quite slow. So not too many specifications could be tried.... The work was done in R. In some other shells, the implementations may have a somewhat different speed.

Comment: Not burst you ML adventures but have you tried Multinomial ? It’s essentially a set of logistic models and will give you more “transparency”. If you expect relationships between dependent and independent to be non linear RF can be a good start. You can move to LightGBM and compare them

Comment: @Gaurav Taneja, there is nothing "transparent" about default. Somebody finally being ready to run on you or commit a suicide is a convolution of so many factors.

Comment: @stans Reality is rarely transparent. When I said transparency I meant the “model” or the “functional approximation” we use to estimate the reality would be more transparent in the sense that one can clearly understand the effect of each variable given its linear nature.

Comment: Understood... Unfortunately, through my project I could see that the impacts are not linear, or simple in any way. All kinds of interactions and special casing are in place. So random forests are naturally suitable.